# how to expose API from windows service application

Tags: c#, windows, api, service

I am working on windows service application that is suppose to perform some tasks. Apart from these tasks, I want to make some of the service functionality available on call. Means, totally separated application should be able to create an object of type specified on windows service and can call some of the functions, decalred public, ofcourse.

Let me know if is there any way to expose the functionality through API or something. if yes, kindly guide me to any tutorial or example of that.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a windows service using WCF to communicate with other applications.

Here's a pretty neat tutorial you can work through:
http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

Comment: The link on this post is dead. Here's the archive.org copy of it: https://web.archive.org/web/20150226030750/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication